# i want to convert a string into Json format and return a vector of string as answer

Tags: c++, json, string

here is input and output format for the problem. 
[] and {} are only acceptable braces in this case.
Assume for this problem that space characters can be done away with.
Your solution should return a list of strings, where each entry corresponds to a single line. The strings should not have “\n” character in them.

Input : `["foo", {"bar":["baz",null,1.0,2]}]`

Output :

```
[
    "foo", 
    {
        "bar":
        [
            "baz", 
            null, 
            1.0, 
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

here is my code i am getting segmentation error, i am new to c++ and unable to find the error in the program  please help

```
vector<string> Solution::prettyJSON(string A) {

    int tabcount=0,j=0;
    vector<string> res;
    cout<<"0st check \n";

    for(int i=0;A[i];i++){


        if(A[i]=='{' || A[i]=='['){

            if(i==0)
                res[j].push_back(A[i]);
            else{    
                j++;
                res[j].insert(0,tabcount,'\t');    
                res[j].push_back(A[i]);
            }

            j++;
            tabcount++;
        }
        else {
            if(A[i]=='}' || A[i]==']'){

                tabcount--;
                j++;
                res[j].insert(0,tabcount,'\t');
                res[j].push_back(A[i]);

                j++;
                }
            else{ 
                if(A[i]==','){

                    res[j].push_back(A[i]);
                    j++;
                    res[j].insert(0,tabcount,'\t');

                    }
                    else{
                        res[j].push_back(A[i]);

                    }
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Segmentation error means you are accessing some area of memory that you do not own. Rest you need to debug

Comment: output format is wrong, there will be no'\n' character instead that part in saved in next row. with proper indentation

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please be aware that there are many C++ JSON parsing and manipulation and prettification libraries, some of which are quite compact and easy to use and only take up a single header. Consider reusing one of those, which will help you avoid the many pitfalls that you'll find when trying to write your own.

---

Now, I'm assuming you haven't debugged this. Running it though visual studio, for example, shows the exact line the crash arises on:

```
res[j].push_back(A[i]);
```

`i` is zero, so this is the very first character. `j` is also zero, but more importantly the **size of `res` is also zero**. This means you're trying to reference a nonexistent entry in `res`, which will, of course, cause your application to crash.

If `j` is equal to or greater than `res.size()`, you'll get this problem, and because you never push any entries into `res` there's no way this code would work. This is probably an indication that you're unfamiliar with using vectors, but this isn't really the place to teach you how to do that.

Anyway, as a minimal fix, if I add `res.push_back("");` before the for loop and after every instance of `j++`, I get this result:

```
[
"foo",

        {
"bar":
                [
"baz",
                        null,
                        1.0,
                        2
                ]

        }

]
```